# Web Setup project not generating .msi file

Tags: asp.net

I have a solution with a web setup project and a large website project in visual studio 2008.
When building the setup project it removes the setup.exe and the .msi file (which it is supposed to), the error occurs when it creates these files.

It creates the setup.exe file but not the .msi file, in its place is a .tmp

Let me know if more information is needed. I am thankful for the help.

Below is the output window and error.

```
------ Build started: Project: C:\...\GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory\, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Validating Web Site
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/19002_DistrictManagement/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/19005_ManualAdjustment/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/19010_AllStatementListing/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/19050_MortgageExport/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/19060_StatementDataExport/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/24570_ParcelPermit/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/29571_OpenSpaceTimberRemoval/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/29572_DFLRemoval/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/29605_ExemptStatusChange/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/29606_DestroyedProperty/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/82005_GDoc_BuildingPermit/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/19097_RelatedSta/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/19098_TxRollCorrect/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/24555_BuildingPermit/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/25030_ParcelSaleHistory/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/25099_QuickValueSummary/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9520_QuickViewAA/9702_GISImaging/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/19097_RelatedSta/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/19098_TxRollCorrect/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/19099_Ownership/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/25030_ParcelSaleHistory/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/25099_QuickValueSummary/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/95020_StatementHeaders/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/9521_QuickViewTR/JS/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/96010_OwnerSummary/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/JS/'.
Building directory '/GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory/'.

Validation Complete
------ Starting pre-build validation for project 'GuwtSetup' ------ 
------ Pre-build validation for project 'GuwtSetup' completed ------
------ Build started: Project: GuwtSetup, Configuration: Release ------
Building file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\svn\GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory\GuwtSetup\Release\GuwtSetup.msi'...
**ERROR: Could not find file 'C:\Documents and Settings\Desktop\svn\GrandUnifiedWebSliceTheory\GuwtSetup\Release\GuwtSetup.msi' 'The system cannot find the file specified.'**
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Figured it out thank you for all the views. The answer was, somehow in the project properties the web setup project release checkbox was marked. Unchecking this box allowed somehow fixed the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out thank you for all the views. The answer was, somehow in the project properties the web setup project release checkbox was marked. Unchecking this box allowed somehow fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Watch the output panel, it will probably indicate what the error is.